# Django forms: List of checkboxes populated from a model

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In `Django` I'm trying to render a list of `checkboxes` with the choices being populated from values in a model's field. Here is what I have so far:

**models**

```
#Model that feeds the list of checkboxes
class Category_Level1(models.Model):
    category_level1_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
```

**forms**

```
class ProductCategoryLevel1Form(forms.Form):
    product_category_level1 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label = "Product Category", choices = Category_Level1.objects.all(), widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

**views**

```
def select_product(request):
    product_category_level1 = ProductCategoryLevel1Form()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product_category_level1_form = ProductCategoryLevel1Form(request.POST)
        if product_category_level1_form.is_valid():
            product_category_level1_list = product_category_level1_form.cleaned_data.get('product_category_level1', 'Unk')
    # Saving the selected categories to another table
            product_cat_obj = Product_Category_Level1(category_level1_name = product_category_level1_list)
            product_cat_obj.save()

    context = {
    'product_category_level1' : product_category_level1
    }

    return render(request, 'select_product/select.html', context)
```

**template**

```
<div class="row">
    <label for="id_prod_category"></label>
    {% product_category_level1 %}
</div>
```

I get the following error:

> Invalid block tag on line 23: 'product_category_level1', expected
>   'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

What am I doing wrong?

Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django uses two types of markup - `{% ... %}` for [tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/language/#tags) and `{{ ... }}` for [variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/language/#variables).

In this code you are trying to render the `product_category_level1` **variable**, therefore you should use `{{ product_category_level1 }}` instead of `{% product_category_level1 %}` in your template.

However, there are also some other bugs in this code.

1. You seem to be mixing `product_category_level1` and `product_category_level1_form` in your view code. These should all be the same variable. You need to use the same variable so when binding the POST data and calling is_valid() the form you display to the user contains any validations errors. As you currently have it you always give the user a new instance of the form - if any data validations fail the form will be presented again with all the fields empty and no error messages.
2. You need to tell Django how you want your form to be rendered - as `p` tags, as `li` tags, etc. As such you'll need to add the method call `as_p` like this: `{{ product_category_level1.as_p }}`. More rendering options can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response. I have corrected the template to have {{ gift_category_level1.as_p }}. I have also corrected the views by having the same variable. Now I get an error which says 'Category_Level1' object is not iterable. But the query set in forms -> choices seems to be ok.

Comment: In forms, I changed the choices from Category_Level1.objects.all() to Category_Level1.objects.values_list('id', 'category_level1_name') and it worked. Thanks for your help!